# flow of program execution of javascript functions in node.js project

Tags: node.js, express

I'm having trouble deleting an item from MongoDB array in a node.js program and found an annoying issue in flow of program execution.
Here's the code:

```
productController.deleteProduct = function(req,res){
  productModel.findById(req.query.id,function(err, product){
    if(err){
      res.send(err);
    }

   if(storeController.deleteStoreProduct(product,res.locals.store,req)){
    product.remove(function(err){
      if(err){
        res.send(err);
      }
      res.send('product deleted successfully');
    });
  }
  else{
    res.send('delete operation failed');
  }
});  
}
```

The above function runs fine. The problem is with the below function.
The above function calls storeController.deleteStoreProduct
Here's the code for storeController.deleteStoreProduct:

```
storeController.deleteStoreProduct = function(product, store, req){
  var isDeleted = false;
  storeModel.findById(store, function(err, foundStore){
    if(product.category === "electronics"){
      if(product.subcategory === "mobiles"){

        console.log('beginning');
        storeModel.update({"storeId":"store-456"}, {'$pull': {"electronics.mobiles": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(product._id)}});
        console.log('yeah done!!');
        isDeleted = true;
      }
    }
  });
  if(isDeleted === true){
    console.log('isdeleted: true');
    return true;
  }
  else{
    console.log('isdeleted: false');
    return false;
  }
}
```

Here in the storeController.deleteStoreProduct function I have written console.log statements just for the debugging purpose.
When I run this program what it has to do is delete a particular item from storeModel collection but instead it outputs just the console.log statements; the console.log statement above the delete statement and the one below that statement executes fine, but the actual delete statement in the middle of these both console.log statements doesn't executes and neither does it throws an error.

**output:**

      `isdeleted: false
      beginning
      yeah done!!`

Instead of running the program from the beginning, it directly goes to last if else statement in storeController.deleteStoreProduct function.
I couldn't understand what is happening here.

**more details:**
arguments in the function `storeController.deleteStoreProduct(product,store,req)` are
1.product
this is an object and is something like this:

```
{
  "name":"asus zenfone 2",
  "category": "electronics",
  "subcategory":"mobiles",
  "details":{
       "specs":["5mp rear cam","2gb ram",16gb rom],
  }
}
```

2.store
store is the _id of the store object in the mongodb.
3.req
This is the request object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is, you are calling asynchronous function storeModel.findById inside your storeController.deleteStoreProduct function and expect storeController.deleteStoreProduct to behave like a synchronous function.

Your storeController.deleteStoreProduct function is **always** going to return **false**.

your code does not print

> isDeleted: true

eventhough item gets deleted properly since code block

```
console.log('isdeleted: true');
return true;
```

never gets executed.

you cant treat storeController.deleteStoreProduct as a synchronous function. You need to treat storeController.deleteStoreProduct as an asynchronous function by either make it a function which accepts a callback or making it a promise returning function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: why doesn't the function return immediately? and neither the update statement works nor it throws an error but the console.log statements above and below the update statement executes.

Comment: storeController.deleteStoreProduct returns immediately ( after executing all statments including the call to storeModel.findById). But the callback to storeModel.findById runs in a later time.